# How to construct a dataframe with LDA in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, lda

Based on 37,000 article texts, I implemented `LDA mallet` topic modeling. Each article was properly categorized and the dominant topic of each was determined.

Now I want to create a dataframe that shows **each topic's percentages for each article**, in Python.

I want the data frame to look like this:

---

```
no |      Text     | Topic_Num_1 | Topic_Num_2 | .... | Topic_Num_25
01 | article text1 |   0.7529    |   0.0034    | .... | 0.0011
02 | article text2 |   0.3529    |   0.0124    | .... | 0.0001
```

....
(37000 x 27 row)

How would I do this?

+

All the code I've been doing is based on the following site.

http://machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python

How can I see the all probability list of the topics of every single article?

Comment: Can you add sample here that how the output looks like?

Comment: Use the saved model and run against the article, and you will get the result that you want.

Comment: Edits for grammar and clarity

Comment: Thank you for the anwsers. All the code I've been doing is based on the following site.  https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358161/efficient-transformation-of-gensim-transformedcorpus-data-to-array) for anyone that has just discovered this question.

I'm also pasting some example code, assuming that you have built a LDA-model and that you want to concatenate the topic-scores to a dataframe df.

```
import gensim
import numpy as np

lda_model = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(corpus, id2word, num_topics)
lda_scores = lda_model[corpus]

all_topics_csr = gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(lda_scores)
all_topics_numpy = all_topics_csr.T.toarray()
all_topics_pandas = pd.DataFrame(all_topics_numpy).reindex(df1.index).fillna(0)

df = pd.concat([df, all_topics_pandas.reindex(df.index)], axis=1, join="inner")
```