# Retrieve per-document topic based on largest probability from LDA gensim

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, matrix, lda

I have an LDA model where I've got the per-document topic probability matrix as per below.

```
doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]
```

How do I extract the topic ID with the largest probability for each document? I'm having difficulty beyond converting `doc_lda` into a list or dataframe.

Coverting it to a list, it looks like a list of a list of a tuple?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on a few people's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574720/python-gensim-lda-add-the-topic-to-the-document-after-getting-the-topics?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919306/find-the-column-name-which-has-the-maximum-value-for-each-row):

```
all_topics = lda_model.get_document_topics(corpus, minimum_probability=0.0)
all_topics_csr = gensim.matutils.corpus2csc(all_topics)
all_topics_numpy = all_topics_csr.T.toarray()
all_topics_df = pd.DataFrame(all_topics_numpy)
all_topics_df.idxmax(axis=1)
```