# fixed-size topics vector in gensim LDA topic modelling for finding similar texts

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, cosine-similarity

I use gensim LDA topic modelling to find topics for each document and to check the similarity between documents by comparing the received topics vectors.
Each document is given a different number of matching topics, so the comparison of the vector (by cosine similarity) is incorrect because vectors of the same length are required.

This is the related code:

```
lda_model_bow = models.LdaModel(corpus=bow_corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=3, passes=1, random_state=47)

#---------------Calculating and Viewing the topics----------------------------
vec_bows = [dictionary.doc2bow(filtered_text.split()) for filtered_text in filtered_texts]

vec_lda_topics=[lda_model_bow[vec_bow] for vec_bow in vec_bows]

for id,vec_lda_topic in enumerate(vec_lda_topics):
    print ('document ' ,id, 'topics: ', vec_lda_topic)
```

The output vectors is:

```
document  0 topics:  [(1, 0.25697246), (2, 0.08026043), (3, 0.65391296)]
document  1 topics:  [(2, 0.93666667)]
document  2 topics:  [(2, 0.07910537), (3, 0.20132676)]
.....
```

As you can see, each vector has a different length, so it is not possible to perform cosine similarity between them.

I would like the output to be:

```
document  0 topics:  [(1, 0.25697246), (2, 0.08026043), (3, 0.65391296)]
document  1 topics:  [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.93666667), (3, 0.0)]
document  2 topics:  [(1, 0.0), (2, 0.07910537), (3, 0.20132676)]
.....
```

Any ideas how to do it? tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [panktijk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10393194/panktijk) says in the comment and also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310925/how-to-get-a-complete-topic-distribution-for-a-document-using-gensim-lda) , the solution is to cange `minimum_probability` from the default value of `0.01` to `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `gensim` for topic modeling before and I had not faced this issue. Ideally, if you pass `num_topics=3` then it returns top 3 topics with the highest probability for each document. And then you should be able to generate the cosine similarity matrix by doing something like this:

```
lda_model_bow = models.LdaModel(corpus=bow_corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=3, passes=1, random_state=47)
vec_lda_topics = lda_model_bow[bow_corpus]
sim_matrix = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(vec_lda_topics)
```

But for some reason, if you are getting unequal number of topics you can assume a zero probability value for the remaining topics and include them in your vector when you calculate similarity.

P.s.: If you could provide a sample of your input documents, it would be easier to reproduce your output and look into it.

Comment: According to the documentation of gensim.ldamodel:
`num_topics (int, optional) – The number of requested latent topics to be extracted from the training corpus.`
If so, this is the total number of topics to which I want to divide the text rather than the top 3.

Comment: Did you also check this parameter: `minimum_probability (float, optional)` – Topics with a probability lower than this threshold will be filtered out? Its default value is `0.01`. It's possible that some of your topics are getting filtered out because of low probability.

Comment: I just found this solution and wanted to update here. That's exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you